# Spring Mvc: An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, rest, jsp, spring-mvc

I work with a `Spring Mvc` app and the front UI looks as the following,

[image]

The landing page maps with the controoler code,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    /**
     * get all the employees of the companies
     * @param modelMap
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/list"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployees(ModelMap modelMap) {

        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.findAllEmployees();
        modelMap.addAttribute("employees", employees);

        return "allemployees";
    }
}
```

Obviously, it shows the `allemployees.jsp` page. When I press the `Add New Employees` link, I get the following error,

```
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

29-Jul-2017 09:43:07.086 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page [/WEB-INF/jsps/registration.jsp] at line [25]

22: 
23: <h2>Registration Form</h2>
24: 
25: <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="employee">
26:     <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
27: 
28:     <table>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.ExpressionEvaluationUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.evaluate(AbstractFormTag.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.resolveModelAttribute(FormTag.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.autogenerateId(FormTag.java:406)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.FormTag.writeTagContent(FormTag.java:353)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsps.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:177)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The `link` tries to open the `registration.jsp` page and the code is here,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Employee Registration Form</title>

    <style>
        .error {
            color: #ff0000;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Registration Form</h2>

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="employee">
    <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="name">Name: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="name" id="name"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="joiningDate">Joining Date: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="joiningDate" id="joiningDate"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="joiningDate" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="salary">Salary: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="salary" id="salary"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="salary" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="ssn">SSN: </label> </td>
            <td><form:input path="ssn" id="ssn"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="ssn" cssClass="error"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${edit}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

<br/>
<br/>
Go back to <a href="<c:url value='/list' />">List of All Employees</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The `GET` request for the `registration.jsp` page is provided,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newEmployees(ModelMap modelMap) {

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        modelMap.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        modelMap.addAttribute("edit", false);

        return "registration";
    }
```

I also see the `URL` links in the Red color in the `Intellij`, e.g,

[image]

[image]

This is the `pom.xml` file I use in the project,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company.employee</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>Practice</artifactId>
    <name>Employees Mgmt</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <!--<version>RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>dbunit</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>LATEST</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!-- testing in Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <!--<warName>SpringHibernateExample</warName>-->
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>SpringHibernateExample</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

The header of the `registration.jsp` page is provided,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

If I carry `Id` as parameter e.g,

```
public String newEmployees(ModelMap modelMap, @RequestParam Integer id{

  // some code 
}
```

the controller code I have,

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newEmployees(ModelMap modelMap, @RequestParam Integer id){

        Employee employee = new Employee();

        modelMap.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        modelMap.addAttribute("edit", false);

        return "registration";
    }
```

Then, I get the following error,

[image]

I get the following error,

I just get started here and the errors feel's so wired. What's the issue here and how to solve it?

Comment: add `@ModelAttribute Employee employee`  in 
`newEmployees` method as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with version inconsistencies across your app for Spring modules. Please note that `ExpressionEvaluationUtils` was deprecated in Spring 3, and has been removed from Spring 4.

Since you're using Spring 3 in WebMVC module, but using Spring 4 in other modules, this problem was likely to occur.

Try to use the same version i.e. `4.3.6.RELEASE` for all of the Spring modules.

Comment: I anticipate this is the correct answer. I will accept the answer after testing. This is indeed a real help and I will updated the template I use for starting the `Spring projects`

Comment: Yes, this is indeed solved. I put this property for setting the version of the dependencies and this work just fine. 

`<properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring_security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring_security.version>
    </properties>`
The later on is obvously for the security related version.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added the dependency of Spring-web in your POM file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please check the version before adding this dependency. It should be same as other Spring dependencies!

Comment: The `dependency` was indeed there. I provided the `pom.xml` file for review of any inconsistency. The issue is surely with the `<form:form>` tag. Even if I put only like 

`<form:form> 
// some code 
</form:form>`

I get the errors in the project.

Comment: use `final releases` instead of `RC snapshots`

Comment: why are you using `@requestparam` and not `@modelattribute` to get the form data in controller?

Answer (score 1):

using the Form tag you need to add the tag libs you can find below`<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>` into jsp page.

and also check that you are add `spring-web` dependency into your pom. you need to use `spring-web` version as per your `SpringFramework`

you can refer below code foe `FORM` tag into jsp page:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="customerForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hidden value :</td>
            <td><form:hidden path="secretValue" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Comment: I have the `spring-web` dependency in the project and later, provided the entire `pom.xml` file in the project.  Could you please have a look for any inconsisitancy?

Comment: now, you can find that i am edited my answer and now, you can find sample and  reference code into my answer for the `form`  tag, you can modify as per you use.

Answer (score 1):

Take "id" as parameter in your newEmployees method:

Replace `public String newEmployees(ModelMap modelMap) {`
with
`public String newEmployees(ModelMap modelMap, @RequestParam(required=false) Integer id) {`

Comment: you will then need to call that page by passing an id like this:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/new?id=(any int value)